# Using a checkmark accessory to show one cell selected in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a settings screen with a selection between two unit systems (Metric and Imperial) and would like to show only one a check mark when the user has selected a specific cell and switch the checkmark if the other cell is selected. Currently my code selects both cells as shown and does't save the check mark to that selected cell when I come back to the view late.

Any ideas on how i can solve this one. I have seen similar questions on stack but most are in ObjC.

Code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        var weightValue: String? = unitsDefaults.objectForKey(kCCWeightKeyMetric) as! String?
        var distanceValue: String? = unitsDefaults.objectForKey(kCCDistanceKeyMetric) as! String?
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)


        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            weightValue = "pounds" //Set to this for the default value of weight
            unitsDefaults.setObject(weightValue, forKey: kCCWeightKeyMetric) //Save the kg value

            distanceValue = "miles" //Set to this for the default value of distance
            unitsDefaults.setObject(distanceValue, forKey: kCCDistanceKeyMetric) //Save the km value

            cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

            unitsDefaults.synchronize()

            //Check mark Selection
            if unitsDefaults.stringForKey(kCCDistanceKeyMetric)! == "miles" {

                cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

            } else if unitsDefaults.stringForKey(kCCDistanceKeyMetric)! == "km"{

                cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            }


        } else {

            weightValue = "kg" //Set to this for the default value of weight
            unitsDefaults.setObject(weightValue, forKey: kCCWeightKeyMetric) //Save the kg value

            distanceValue = "km" //Set to this for the default value of distance
            unitsDefaults.setObject(distanceValue, forKey: kCCDistanceKeyMetric) //Save the km value

            unitsDefaults.synchronize()

            //Check mark Selection
            if unitsDefaults.stringForKey(kCCDistanceKeyMetric)! == "km" {

                cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

            } else if unitsDefaults.stringForKey(kCCDistanceKeyMetric)! == "miles"{

                cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            }


        }

        //Dismiss the View
        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of data source do you use for that table view?

Comment: I'm using static cells as static prototypes. Hence there is no data source? Should I be using one or is there another way?

Comment: If the cells are static you actually don't need `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because you can reference everything static with `IBOutlet`s.

Comment: Thanks. Creating the iBOutlets actually worked. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do this type. I am writing in Objective-C. You can get Idea how to perform in Swift.
Create a mutable dictionary say 'cellDictionary'

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellRowString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
     if([cellDictionary valueForKey:cellRowString]!=nil){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellRowString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
    if([cellDictionary valueForKey:cellRowString]==nil){
        [cellDictionary setObject:cellRowString forKey:cellRowString];
    }
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I have the cells as static prototypes. Does this mean I should make them dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this one might be your problem. Just in case...don't forger to reset accesory on prepareforreuse (subclass UITableViewCell).

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: it would be more normal to reset the accessory type in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function in the enclosing `UITableViewController`

Comment: yes, this one was referring in case the cell is subclassed

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using static cells, I created IBOutlets for those two cells and did a check in the View did load which workout well.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var firstCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondCell: UITableViewCell!

    var unitsDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Check mark Selection
        if unitsDefaults.stringForKey(kCCDistanceKeyMetric)! == "miles" {

            firstCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            secondCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

        } else if unitsDefaults.stringForKey(kCCDistanceKeyMetric)! == "km"{

            firstCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            secondCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

        }
       ....

    }
```